# Ngfor to array and access via ngif

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I am trying to have basically a read more on a post that is created using Angular NgFor loop. I have my data printing out just fine, but I have tried a bunch of different things to get NgFor to push to an array or something so that one I click on a post to show more data it doesn't open all of the posts on the page. Right now, if I click on one post to show more, all the posts on the page expand to show more content.

Here is a snip of my code that is running the NgFor loop and the NgIf. Any suggestions on how to push to an array?

```
<tr *ngFor="let policy of needs; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="!this.isInfoVisible">
      <a href="" class="listing-link"  (click)="this.isInfoVisible = true">
      <table class="needs-posting">
      {{i}}
```

I tried to do something like this, but was only getting errors:

```
<tr *ngFor="let policy of needs; let i = index; addPost()">
      <div *ngIf="this.isInfoVisible[{{i}}] = false">
      <a href="" class="listing-link"  (click)="this.isInfoVisible[{{i}}] = true">
      <table class="needs-posting">
      {{i}}
```

with

```
addPost()
{
     this.isInfoVisible.push(false);
}
```

I don't know if I am onto the correct concept, but just with wrong syntax or something. First time using Angular here. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share a minimal reproduction on stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are binding to `isInfoVisible` that is in the code `<div *ngIf="!this.isInfoVisible">` this indicates that the value will display when `isInfoVisible` is `true`. When of `isInfoVisible` turns to `true` all the contents display because each of the contents is bound to this.

Try below approach.
In your TS file

```typescript
  isInfoVisible: boolean[] = [false]
```

In your html

```html
<tr *ngFor="let policy of needs; let i = index">
      <div *ngIf="!this.isInfoVisible[i]">
      <a href="" class="listing-link"  (click)="this.isInfoVisible[i] = true">
      <table class="needs-posting">
      {{i}}
```

With the above, each item will be bound to a specific index in the property `isInfoVisible`

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm. I had the right idea I think, I just was using the wrong syntax.